# Rspec: spec case classified as flaky

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, bdd

I'm trying to write some tests (spec) using rspec, so far, I'm getting the next example as flaky:

```
      it "when filter by date_of_birth is present" do
        get :index, filter: { 'event_timestamps.date_of_birth': format_date(recorded_at + 6.hours) }, format: :json
        expect(json_data.count).to eq(1)
      end
```

I supposed the issue is in the parameters, I'm not sure, so my questions are:

1. Should format in a different way the params?
2. is my approach wrong? what should be a better one?

Thanks a lot for your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing the problem is within 6 hours of the end of the day when your time calculation will be pushing the date into "tomorrow", generally the best idea with anything like that is to use a gem like timecop so you're not relying on an ever-changing state.

Comment: I see, I never heard about that gem, so if I get this correctly, should I replace my 6.hours with the implementation of timecop gem? sorry if the question is repetitive, I'm just double checking

Comment: The timecop gem will allow you to just ensure the "time the test thinks it is" is consistent (eg. midday of the given day) so that your time calculation is then also consistent.